# Regroup JSON file in a new format

Tags: python, json

I'm need a little help reordering this JSON data:

**I've this file at this moment:**

```
[{"aName":{"name":"somename","vendor":"vendor1"}},
 {"bName":{"name":"somename","vendor":"vendor2"}},
 {"cName":{"name":"othername","vendor":"vendor1"}
}]
```

**I need re order it like this:**

```
[{"name":"vendor1"},
 {"child":[{"name":"somename","id":"aName"},
           {"name":"othername","id":"cName"}]},
 {"name":"vendor2"},
 {"child":[{"name":"somename","id":"bName"}]}]
```

I was trying with this:

```
new format = []

for i in old_format:
    new_format.setdefault(i['vendor'], []).append({"children":{"name":i['name'],"id":i}})
```

it's "closer", but not what I want

```
{
       "vendor1":[
          {
             "children":{
                "name":"somename",        
                "id":"aName"
             }
          },
          {
             "children":{
                "name":"othername",
                "id":"cName"
             }
          }
       ],
       "vendor2":[
          {
             "children":{
                "name":"somename",
                "id":"bName"
             }
          }
       ]
    }
```

I'll appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data representation you're using is a little strange... You have a lot of dictionaries with one entry, which suggests to me that you'd be better off rethinking how you store your data.

That said, this bit of code should do what you want:

```
vendors = {}
for entry in data:
    for identifier, info in entry.items():
        children = vendors.setdefault(info['vendor'], [])
        children.append({
            'name': info['name'],
            'id': identifier
            })

res = []
for vendor, children in vendors.items():
    res.append({'name': vendor})
    res.append({'child': children})
```

Here `data` is your input -- a list of dictionaries -- and `res` is the result:

```
[{'name': 'vendor2'},
 {'child': [{'id': 'bName', 'name': 'somename'}]},
 {'name': 'vendor1'},
 {'child': [{'id': 'aName', 'name': 'somename'},
   {'id': 'cName', 'name': 'othername'}]}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jme. The file has to be formatted like that because it will be used in a sublime text plugin, so I can't do anything with it. I've been testing the code and when I try it, this line `children.append({'name': info['name'],'id': identifier})` give some error, the problem is ST did not show me the error, but is where the code stops, I tried with `children.append("name")` and is the same

Comment: my bad, I had a typo in the `append` name now is all working, Thanks again!